# Overfull box warning when breaking line with accent word in LaTex

Tags: latex, line-breaks, diacritics

I am writting a document in Spanish in LaTeX and the overfull box warning pops up. It is because LaTeX is trying to break the line with a word that has an accent. 
Because of this, that part of the document looks kind of bad because it goes over the margin.
Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried Try the `sloppypar` enviroment in latex? it tells `LaTeX` to adjust word spacing less strictly.

`\begin{sloppypar}
%your word / paragraph
\end{sloppypar}`

Comment: Just in case other will need this answer for their own problems I will post this as the answer, please verify the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `sloppypar` enviroment in latex, it tells `LaTeX` to adjust word spacing less strictly.

`\begin{sloppypar}
%your word / paragraph
\end{sloppypar}`